# TextBox Mouse Double click

Tags: wpf, textbox, mouseevent

I have a `TextBox` and a `Button` in my form. I enter some text and when I double click the mouse it should call the `Button` Command,CommandParameter. Is this possible?

There is no code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Button Template, that internally has a TextBox (maybe with IsHitTestVisible set to false and an outer Grid with Transparent Background).
Then you can bind your command directly to this "TextBox-Button".

Edit: Source code:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <TextBox />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>

  <Button Content="Test" />
</Grid>
```

And invoke the command via Attached Behavior Pattern like described [here](http://www.bjoernrochel.de/2009/08/19/the-attached-behavior-pattern/) and [here](http://eladm.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/attached-behavior/).

Andrej

Comment: <Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate>
  <TextBox Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
     </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
  </Style>
 </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="107,114,96,90" x:Name="button1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Background="Transparent" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
    </Grid>

Comment: Try moving the Grid around the TextBox in the Template and setting IsHitTestVisible on the TextBox and not on the Button

Comment: I just tried it out, put *only* the TextBox in the template without IsHitTestVisible and handle the MouseDoubleClick-Event of the Button - it works :)

Comment: If you insist on having no code behind, you can use the Attached Behavior Pattern (infos: http://www.bjoernrochel.de/2009/08/19/the-attached-behavior-pattern/) to invoke a Command when doubleclicking

Comment: I tried to mark as answer but it says Vote up requires 15 reputation